# Converting 'Chrome tracer' results to firefox profiler format

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

Basically the title.

I would like to profile an application manually and use the firefox profiler as illustration. For that i need a very basic file format where i can insert data in the json format but i can't find a concise specification of the firefox profiling data format.

Chrome has a very clear and easy to understand [format guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CvAClvFfyA5R-PhYUmn5OOQtYMH4h6I0nSsKchNAySU/edit#heading=h.f2f0yd51wi15) with a minimal json object that can be loaded and viewed in the chrome profiler.

```
{
  "name": "myName",
  "cat": "category,list",
  "ph": "B",
  "ts": 12345,
  "pid": 123,
  "tid": 456,
  "args": {
    "someArg": 1,
    "anotherArg": {
      "value": "my value"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to build a similar json file for the [Firefox profiler](https://profiler.firefox.com/).